# WPF TabControl - when DataContext changes, can I prevent 'de-selection' of the previous DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl, which contains a composite collection.  The composite collection consists of 1 "static" TabItem, and a collection of data-bound items, located in a ViewModel:

```
<TabControl x:Name="myCompositeTabs"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CloseableTabItem}" 
            Style="{StaticResource ScrollableTabControl}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CloseableTabItemHeaderDataTemplate}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="boundTabCollection" Source="{Binding MyItems}" />
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabControl.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <TabItem x:Name="summaryTab" Header="Summary">
                    <views:SummaryView />
                </TabItem>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource boundTabCollection}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </TabControl.ItemsSource>
    </TabControl>
```

The DataContext of the TabControl changes frequently, because the TabControl itself represents the currently-selected item of completely separate collection of ViewModels - a 'collection of collections,' if you will.

The issue I'm experiencing is; the native behavior of the TabControl appears to 'reset' the SelectedIndex to -1, during a DataContext switch.  So every time the user picks a different ViewModel, the TabControl 'resets' the selected index of the previously-selected ViewModel.  I don't want it to do that; I want it to leave the SelectedIndex alone, when the context is switching - each ViewModel should be able to keep track of its own SelectedIndex value.

...How would I go about preventing this 'reset'?  I tried catching it in the "DataContextChanged" event, but that seems to be too late; that event is raised *after* the selected index has already been reset on the 'old' ViewModel.

Comment: Here's an idea for you for the part that you don't want reset Bind it to a non changing datacontext.  Or it's okay if the content of the context changes just make sure it's all handled properly.  For example you could have a DataContext that binds the Tab Control's Selected Tab and nothing else.

Comment: I want each ViewModel to track it's own currently-selected Tab.  When users switch between contexts, it should remember what the selected tab was for that context, when last it was selected.

Comment: Okay so you only have limited options,  1) Each viewmodel is statically a creation of the View giving you the ability to use any type of backing store for the current selected tab index.  The key here is that the viewmodel is static.  The datacontext can bind to the static tab index property whose backing store is it's own private instance of an Integer.  Therefore because that value never changes until you tell it to change, you can swap data context in and out at will.

Comment: Have the set not honor a -1.  In the get verify the SelectedIndex is in range.

Comment: I don't know the CompositeCollection, but it seems implementing the INotifyCollectionChanged, as the ObservableCollection and that's fine. What's not probably fine, is the "Reset" state behavior of the implementation, which adheres the interface but does not play fair with WPF. In other words, the CC may decide to empty then refill the collection upon a certain convenience, this obviously "resets" the TabControl selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a multitude of custom behaviors, event handlers, and data binding combinations, I've come to the conclusion that the CompositeCollection doesn't play nice with the TabControl, when mixing static and data-bound items.

I pushed my "Summary Tab" contents into the VM, and now everything seems to be working.